# How can I write a SQL query with multiple COUNTs for different GROUP BYs?

Tags: mysql, sql

One of my coworkers is working on a SQL query. After several joins (workers to accounts to tasks), she's got some information sort of like this:

```
Worker       Account    Date        Task_completed
Bob Smith    12345      01/01/2010  Received
Bob Smith    12345      01/01/2010  Received
Bob Smith    12345      01/01/2010  Processed
Sue Jones    23456      01/01/2010  Received
...
```

Ultimately what she wants is something like this - for each date, for each account, how many tasks did each worker complete for that account?

```
Worker       Account    Date        Received_count  Processed_count
Bob Smith    12345      01/01/2010  2               1
```

... and there are several other statuses to count.

Getting **one** of these counts is pretty easy:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(Task_completed)
FROM 
  (the subselect)
WHERE 
  Task_completed = 'Received'
GROUP BY
  worker, account, date
```

But I'm not sure the best way to get them all. **Essentially we want multiple `COUNT`s using different `GROUP BY`s**. The best thing I can figure out is to copy and paste the subquery several times, change the `WHERE` to "Processed", etc, and join all those together, selecting just the count from each one.

Is there a more obvious way to do this?

Comment: A question!   Why in your example say in Processed_count = 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  worker, account, date,
        SUM(task_completed = 'Received') AS received_count,
        SUM(task_completed = 'Processed') AS processed_count
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        worker, account, date
```

Comment: Ah! `SUM` on a conditional - that's what I was missing. *Much* simpler. I guess I've only used that for numeric fields. Thanks!

Comment: @Nathan: in `MySQL`, `BOOLEAN` is just an alias for `TINYINT`.